# Can I use pseudo-distributed HBase in production?

Tags: hbase, production, minimum

The problem is that we have a range of customers and some of them doesn't need the scale HBase is designed for. For these customers couple of nodes is not an option.

For them we would like to run HBase in pseudo-distributed mode on RAID5. Customer doesn't require failsafe for the service. He just need that data will be safe on RAID5.

Official guide clearly states that pseudo-distributed mode isn't ment for a production use. I can imagine that this statement is due to fact that there is no failsafe for the service, the performance isn't the best.

But technically I believe that it can run in this mode long-term if above features aren't required for the customer. Or are some other issues? Possibly it isn't well tested in this setup?

We don't want to introduce another single node database in our application just to address couple of customers. We need HBase for large customers.

Answer (score 1):

HBase can be run in standalone mode, pseudo-distributed  mode,  or  fully  distributed  mode.  Standalone  and  pseudo-distributed  modes  are  only  for  **testing**  and  **playing**  around;  they  aren’t  intended  for
use  in  a  production  environment. 
Using  pseudo-distributed is too unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

It is what guide states. But I can't find anywhere what is the actual problem with the pseudo-installation (except the obvious failsafe and possibly performance). To my understanding it should technically work. It would be nice to know details so I can evaluate if it is a problem for our use case.

If I would virtualize a single machine into 4-5 nodes then it would be fine? Note, I don't mind performance that much nor the missing failsafe. Just the stability.

What is the accepted node minimum for replication factor 3? 3 nodes?